# What Kubernetes API endpoint can I use to see if there are unscheduled pods?

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core

I am trying to write a .net core application to run in a kubernetes pod.  This application needs to know if the cluster has been unable to schedule any pods.

I have tried getting deployment data from

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments
```

I can see the `unavailableReplicas` number and the `MinimumReplicasUnavailable` message.

Are these valid metrics to watch for the cluster status?

Is there a way to query the cluster as a whole instead of by deployment?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5207) github thread and considered using `DesiredState.Host=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for the images in each node in the cluster you can try

```
kubectl get nodes -o json
```

which will return a json object or using **--field-selector** as shown below.

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector=status.phase==Pending
```

and using api

```
kubectl get --raw /api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=status.phase==Pending
```

Comment: It does not have list of pods or containers.